# ¿Por qué PHP no me permite realizar subconsultas SQL?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

**Trato de ejecutar esta consulta `SQL` en PHP:**

```
SELECT 
        M000.FULTACT000,
        M000.NBCLI000, 
        M000.G300CTA,
        (SELECT NCNL000 FROM BI_SRC.CNLF000 WHERE CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000),
        (SELECT NALDF000 FROM BI_SRC.ALDF000 WHERE IDALDF000 = M000.IDALDF000),
        (SELECT NBUSUF000 FROM BI_SRC.USEJE000 WHERE UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000)

FROM   

BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000

ORDER BY 

M000.MRCJID000 DESC;
```

En la base de datos de **Oracle**, todo va bien, pero al implementarlo en PHP (las subconsultas) me arroja un par de errores. Entre ellos:

> Undefined index: NCNL000 Undefined index: NALDF000 Undefined
>   index: NBUSUF000

**CODIGO ACTUALIZADO EN PHP**

```
$stid = $conn->prepare("SELECT M000.FULTACT000, M000.NBCLI000, M000.G300CTA, (SELECT C000.NCNL000 FROM BI_SRC.CNLF000 C000 WHERE C000.CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000),(SELECT NALDF000 FROM BI_SRC.ALDF000 WHERE IDALDF000 = M000.IDALDF000),(SELECT NBUSUF000 FROM BI_SRC.USEJE000 WHERE UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000)

        FROM   BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000

        ORDER BY M000.MRCJID000 DESC");

    $stid->execute();

    while ($row = $stid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {// obtener resultados está línea hace falta
        $fecha[] = $row['FULTACT000'];
        $cliente[] = $row['NBCLI000'];
        $cuenta[] = $row['G300CTA'];
        $canal[] = $row['NCNL000'];
        $aliado[] = $row['NALDF000'];
        $gerente[] = $row['NBUSUF000'];
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP tiene razón, no existe ese índice en los resultados, el índice se llama

```
 SELECT NCNL000 FROM BI_SRC.CNLF000 WHERE CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000
```

Así, per sé. Si pegas esa consulta en tu DB verás que los encabezados que regresa no se llaman NCNL000 si no toda la consulta. Eso lo solucionas poniendole el alias que necesitas

```
SELECT 
M000.FULTACT000, 
M000.NBCLI000, 
M000.G300CTA, 
(SELECT C000.NCNL000 FROM BI_SRC.CNLF000 C000 WHERE C000.CUUID000 = M000.CUUID000) AS 'NCNL000',
(SELECT NALDF000 FROM BI_SRC.ALDF000 WHERE IDALDF000 = M000.IDALDF000) AS 'NALDF000',
(SELECT NBUSUF000 FROM BI_SRC.USEJE000 WHERE UIDEJE000 = M000.UIDEJE000) AS 'NBUSUF000'
FROM BI_SRC.MRCJ000 M000
ORDER BY M000.MRCJID000 DESC
```

**Agrego**, ¿Por qué estás haciendo subconsultas en lugar de JOINS? En consultas grande le pegarás al performance de la DB, es mejor normalizar desde ahora y ahorrarte el problema.

Que te sirva.

Comment: +1 , como el OP modificó su pregunta con el problema anterior solucionado, para lo segundo su respuesta está mejor explicada  que la mía.